# Get path to a directory file

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to get the path to a file in my tmp/ directory (below) from inside my template. Is there anyway I could do this? Many thanks in advance.

```
Eg: 
<img src = "{% url 'tmp' %}/<my_file>">
or 
<img src ="/tmp/<my_file>">

mysite/ 
|--- mysite/  
|--- myapp/  
|--- tmp/  
|--- manage.py   
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). You're going to need to add the directory to the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting, load the template tags in the template with `{% load staticfiles %}` then generate the url with `{% static "file" %}`. Make sure you're reading the correct documentation for your Django version.